# offset shadow/blurry text HP Photosmart C4780 with HPLIP

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and HPLIP 3.20.3 I have an HP Photosmart C4780. I have genuine HP ink catridges. Black text prints blurry: there is a gray shadow of every character approximately 1mm below it which is made of a mosaic of coloured dots. If I switch the printing mode to "Black-only Grayscale" black text prints clearly. Colour photographs print clearly in colour mode. Text in any colour other than black prints fine in colour modes. But if I have a document to print that contains some colours anywhere and black text, I have no way to print it clearly. The printer's print Quality diagnostic report does NOT have the problem. A colour photocopy that includes clear black text is clear. The HPLIP testpage does have the problem.

Comment: Change the output print quality, or paper type, to higher settings, and it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 and the same printer. Here's how I solved it:

1. Installed HPLIP 3.21.2 from (https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip). I'm not sure this step is really needed.
2. Aligned the cartridges 3 or 4 times. In the command line type:

   hp-align -p <printer_name>

and just follow the instructions for alignment.